# Not able to use Docker command inside Ubuntu based docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to run few Docker commands inside my Ubuntu 20.04 docker container, which contains a shell script used to trigger Docker commands. I installed  the Docker.io in my Dockerfile, and when I tried to run `sudo service docker status` command inside scripts, it showed 'unrecognized service' error, and if I run `docker create` command it says

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

So my question is: is it not enough to just install docker.io in order to run docker command in Ubuntu based container? Or is it wrong to use docker.io? Thanks!

Below is the Dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install software-properties-common && \
  apt-get -y install docker.io && \
  apt-get -y install vim && \
  apt-get -y install gzip && \
  apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg

RUN mkdir -p /latest

COPY run.sh /latest/

RUN chmod 755 /latest/run.sh

RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | \
  tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | \
  apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && apt-get update -y && apt-get install google-cloud-cli -y
```

Comment: You either need to run the Docker daemon, or connect back to the host's Docker socket.  The linked question describes both approaches.  A container only runs a single process, so it would be tricky to both run a Docker-in-Docker container and also have it start its own processes.

Comment: More generally, in between the security implications of getting access to the Docker socket (it's very easy to use it to compromise the host) and the limits of tying your self to the Docker API (it'd be hard to run your application either in a non-container environment or in cluster environments like Kubernetes) you also might consider whether you _really_ need to be able to dynamically launch containers.